# Aborting external long running api request inside a Vercel serverless function

Tags: api, next.js, serverless, vercel

I have a request in a Vercel serverless function to an external API using node fetch inside a serverless function. I do not want this to be long running so my plan is to abort the external request if it takes longer than a second.

Is this a good strategy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a valid approach.

Serverless functions in the Vercel Hobby plan already have a [built-in timeout of 10s](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/limits/overview#general-limits), so maybe you don't even need to worry about doing this yourself.

If you choose to do this, I would recommend increasing the timeout duration. It is common for an API request to take longer than a second ("depends", of course). But maybe a timeout of *3s* or *5s* is good enough.

Comment: Many thanks, yeah maybe I won’t be so tight with the timeout as suggested.